# Material buttons having default gap between them when aligned in a column widget

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have 2 textbutton inside a column widget. But they have default spacing between them. It doesn't happen with row. How to remove these gap? [ Using flutter latest stable version ] [image: ScreenShot]

Comment: In Flutter, the distance between widgets inside is determined by the **mainAxisAlignment**  and **crossAxisAlignment** properties. They are set by default, but you can override them. Here is the link to the (documentation)[https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics#mainaxisalignment-property]

Comment: Also please post your code, not a screenshot of the code. If you could provide code then I could help more. Thanks

Comment: I tried padding:  EdgeInsets.zero, but no luck.

Comment: Can you provide code, not a picture?
And I can help with the solution faster

Comment: https://ideone.com/KUQb5Q

Comment: https://ideone.com/NWLswt

Comment: https://ideone.com/4iyPKn

Comment: I ran your code and this is what [I see](https://imgur.com/xg6VHin). Either the problem has already been solved or you have provided incorrect code.

Comment: @IvanAbakumov Thanks for your time. One last request! I have written a simple and fresh code. Please run it. Also please share your Android Studio and Flutter version. Mine  is Giraffe 2023.3.1 and 3.10.6. And a screenshot of the emulator.

Comment: https://ideone.com/0VQzor